# Setting the default value in multiselect in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I use the React bootstrap Typeahead library (https://github.com/ericgio/react-bootstrap-typeahead). My problem is that based on the indexes `this.state.todo` I need to find objects with given indexes inside`this.state.todos`. Display names of found objects as defaults in multiselect.

Demo here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rsfpup

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      todos: [{id:1, name: 'Paul'}, {id:2, name: 'Martin'}, {id:3, name: 'Jacob'}],
      todo:[1, 3],
      selectedItems: []
    };
  }

  handleSelect = items => {

    this.setState({ selectedItems: items });
  };

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <Todos 
          todos={this.state.todos}
          todo={this.state.todo}
          handleSelect = {this.handleSelect}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Todos extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    var tempArr = this.props.todos.filter(item => !this.props.todo.includes(item));



    return (
      <div>
        <Typeahead
          id={'example4'}
          labelKey="name"
          multiple
          selected={tempArr}
          options={this.props.todos}
          onChange={this.props.handleSelect}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Umbro, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this,

```
let selected = this.state.todos.map( (todo, index) => {
   if(this.state.todo.includes(index)){  //compare based on index
      return todo
   }
})
```

---

If you want to compare based on `id` in `this.state.todos`,

```
let selected = this.state.todos.map( (todo, index) => {
   if(this.state.todo.includes(todo.id)){  //compare based on id in this.state.todos
      return todo
   }
})
```

---

**Update**

Based on your demo example, you need to set the `selectedItems` in your `App` component only and need to pass the same to your `Todos` component.

```
componentDidMount(){
    //Based on index
    this.setState({
      selectedItems: this.state.todos.filter( (todo, index) => this.state.todo.includes(index))
    })

    //Based on id in this.state.todos
    // this.setState({
    //   selectedItems: this.state.todos.filter( (todo, index) => this.state.todo.includes(todo.id))
    // })
}
```

**Note:** Instead of `map`, you need to use `filter` here.

Pass the `selectedItems` to `Todos` component,

```
<Todos 
    todos={this.state.todos}
    todo={this.state.todo}
    handleSelect = {this.handleSelect}
    selectedItems = {this.state.selectedItems}  //Pass selectedItems here
/>
```

In `Todos` component, you need to use `selectedItems`

```
<Typeahead
    id={'example4'}
    labelKey="name"
    multiple
    selected= {this.props.selectedItems}  //Use selectedItems here
    options={this.props.todos}
    onChange={this.props.handleSelect}
/>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vmju8x)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is because todos is an array of object and todo is an array of integer, therefore when you do the filter, it will not work, you would have to use the todos.id. ex:

```
var tempArr = this.props.todos.filter(item => !this.props.todo.includes(item.id));
```